# Свой секундомер в игру,способы и имеющиеся в java методы

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Захотелось в игру сделать секундомер. Я представляю это так: системное время идет и я в соответствии с ним выставляю изображения цифр. Есть ли готовые методы или пусть даже доп. библиотеки для добавления своих размеров и изображений к секундомеру?  Стоит ли его реализовывать в доп потоке? А если уже есть один доп. поток стоит ли еще один доп. поток для секундомера создавать? Наверно стоит создать массив изображений цифр в чем будет его плюс?

Comment: есть хорошая книга про то как делать игры - http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Comment: Действительно материал судя по содержанию кажется интересным, как раз читаю свою первую книгу на анг. Head First java , тяжело с переводом пока что, но решил идти на пролом, тупо брать и читать как получается. Прочту и эту книгу, но пока интересует прямой ответ на мой вопрос, так как хочу в игрушку секундомер доделать.

Comment: новичкам не стоит начинать с игр. но если очень хочется именно игр, то посмотрите вот на это http://www.greenfoot.org/door

Comment: движки не интересуют, тем более такого высокого уровня. немного AndEngine попробовал, документации нет, решил сам движок писать, с горем по полам знаний полученных за полтора годы программирования на Qbasic и позже на Visual basic хватает. Самое важное что мне сейчас нужно , это побольше исходников игр под андроид, нужны те самые примитивные артихектуры. Но это всё потом, пока что я иду на пролом и хочу закончить начатую игру, осталось только меню да секундомер. Насчет меню тоже вроде разобрался, буду так же на канве рисовать как и игру.

Comment: А вот секундомер хотел написать собственный. Неужели нет готового класса, где уже можно и размер секундомера установить и изображения цифр свои. И вот еще вопрос : Насколько понизит производительность использование изображений для цифр, вместо другого шрифта

Comment: вероятность найти готовое решение возрастает, если это нужно большому количеству людей. секундомер для игры к этому не относится.

Comment: Ну и пусть.  Буду тогда свой класс писать. Ну и еще гляну  java готовые решения в классе таймер